# ¿Cómo puedo quitar los acentos en python?

Tags: python-3.x

les pongo en contexto, mi programa pregunta si quiere una pizza vegetariana, al ponerlo puedes ponerlo con acento, pero si eso pasa no me lo detecta con el if.
También intento que la variable al pasar por el if la cadena de texto se ponga en minúscula para que independientemente de si lo ponen en mayúscula o minúscula lo detecte.

```
TipoPizza = input("¿Quieres una pizza vegetariana? (Si es que no, ponga 'no'): ")
a,b = 'í', 'i'
trans = str.maketrans(a,b)

if TipoPizza.translate.lower(trans) == "no":
    print("no")
elif TipoPizza.translate.lower(trans) == "si":
    print("si")
```

Si quito el .lower del código funciona, me transforma el sí por un 'si', pero me gustaría poner el lower para que me detecte siempre aunque escriban en mayúscula.

Comment: Lo que intentas sería `TipoPizza.translate(trans).lower()` pero me parece demasiada complicación. Para este caso es más simple `if TipoPizza.lower() in ["si", "sí"]`

Answer (score 4):

De forma más general, y porque eventualmente puede ser útil, es posible eliminar un eventual acento mediante el módulo [`unicode`](https://pypi.org/project/Unidecode/), aunque por lo comentarios tiene ciertos temas según el idioma, le remoción de acentos es un tema dependiente del idioma y sus reglas.

```
cadena_con_acentos = 'áéíóú'

import unidecode
cadena_sin_acentos = unidecode.unidecode(cadena_con_acentos)

print(cadena_sin_acentos)
aeiou
```

O bien, usar el módulo base `unicodedata`:

```
cadena_con_acentos = 'áéíóú'

import unicodedata
def strip_accents(s):
   return ''.join(c for c in unicodedata.normalize('NFD', s)
                  if unicodedata.category(c) != 'Mn')

print(strip_accents(cadena_con_acentos))
```

fuente: [What is the best way to remove accents (normalize) in a Python unicode string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-normalize-in-a-python-unicode-string)

Answer (score 2):

Esta alternativa considera todas versiones de Si, Sí, No, no.

Primero se reduce la entrada a minúsculas, con lo que sólo resta comparar contra las respuestas válidas en minúsculas.

```
while True:
    r = input("Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) ").strip().lower()
    if r == 'no':
        print("Opción no")
    elif r in ['si', 'sí']:
        print("Opción si")
    else:
        print("Opción no válida")
```

produce:

```
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) No
Opción no
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) no
Opción no
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) SI
Opción si
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) SÍ
Opción si
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) si
Opción si
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) sI
Opción si
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No) sÍ
Opción si
Pizza vegetariana (Si/No)
```

Comment: La funcionalidad de strip() es deshacerse de los espacios en blanco anteriores y posteriores a las letras introducidas (en el caso de que se use sin argumentos), si he entendido bien. Más información y ejemplos (en inglés): https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_strip.asp

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar un replace:

> TipoPizza = TipoPizza.replace("í", "i")

Te sustituye todas las veces que vea una "í" por una "i".

aquí tiens más detalles: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-replace/

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el usuario escribe SÍ (todo en mayúsculas)?

Comment: TipoPizza = TipoPizza.lower().replace("í", "i")   de esta forma primero convierte a minúsculas y luego sustituye la "í" por la "i"

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un `if` de esta manera

```
if (TipoPizza == 'sí')
     TipoPizza = 'si'
```

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el usuario escribe SÍ?

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    tipoPizza = input("¿Quieres una pizza vegetariana? (Si/No): ")
    vegetariana = None
    if tipoPizza[0] in ("S", "s") and tipoPizza[1] in ("i", "í", "I", "Í"):
        vegetariana = True
        break
    elif tipoPizza in ("No", "no", "NO"):
        vegetariana = False
        break
    else:
        print("Por favor, introduzca un valor válido (Si/No)")
```

Se pregunta al usuario si quiere una pizza vegetariana. Si la respuesta es afirmativa, se asigna a la variable `vegetariana` el valor `True`. Si es negativa, se asigna `False`.

Una funcionalidad interesante es que para cualquier otro valor introducido se pida que se vuelva a escribir un valor, y así hasta que sea válido. Con el bucle `while` se consigue este propósito.

Comment: ¿Qué pasa si el usuario ingresa SI ... todo en mayúsculas?

Comment: Gracias, ahora también se contempla esa posibilidad

Comment: ¿Y que pasa si ingresa sI ('s' en minúscula, 'I' en mayúsculas)?

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, lo he mejorado

Comment: ¿Por qué motivo pones las variables en minúscula? ¿Pasa algo al ponerles "TipoPizza" en vez de "tipoPizza"?

Comment: Según la guía de estilo de Python, los nombres de funciones y de variables se deben escribir con la letra inicial minúscula: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-variable-names